# read fails with EFAULT

Tags: c, linux

I am running the following C code, where trying to read in buffer which
is allocated on caller's stack, but fails with errno 14 (Bad Address).

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void wrapper(int fd, char **buf)
{
  int res = read(fd, *buf, 10);

  printf("res: %d, errno: %d\n", res, errno);

  printf("Buf: %s\n", *buf);
}

int main()
{
  char buffer[10];

  memset(buffer, 0, 10);

  int fd = open("main.c", O_RDONLY);

  wrapper(fd, (char **)&buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
res: -1, errno: 14
Buf: (null)
```

I have been searching for explanation why it fails, whereas changing it to

```
void wrapper(int fd, char *buf)
...
wrapper(fd, (char *)buffer);
```

works, but without result so far.

Comment: `wrapper(fd, (char **)&buffer);` buffer is not a pointer. So, `&buffer` is not a pointer to pointer.

Comment: But 
    `printf("%p\n", buffer); `
prints the addres of array.

Comment: And what is the address of this addres?

Comment: @wildplasser `0x7ffff9057050`

Comment: Really? Print `buffer` and `&buffer`. What do you get?

Comment: `printf("buffer: %p\n", buffer);


 printf("&buffer: %p\n", &buffer);`

`buffer: 0x7ffd6a02fba0
&buffer: 0x7ffd6a02fba0`

Comment: @usr Right, inside `void wrapper(int fd, char **buf) ` when printing `*buf` it is `(nil)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why it fails

Arrays are not pointers. `buffer` is not a `char*`. Consequently, `&buffer` is not a `char**`, is not compatible with `char**`, and should not be cast to `char**`. If it is cast to `char**` and then dereferenced, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Seems you're right, when casting to `char **` and then dereference it is `(nil)` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzed your intention, of course it is possible to create something like a "wrapper" containing read string by `read(2)` syscall and use that buffer away from `wrapper()` function. You wanted to pass amount of characters which would be read from file being in a table of files whom index of the table (file descriptor) was return by `open(2)` syscall. But as n.m. said, arrays are not pointers and your solution cannot work properly.

Let me explain my simple fix to your code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define AMOUNT 20

#define assert_msg(x) for ( ; !(x) ; assert(x) )

void
wrapper(int fd, char **buf, size_t size)
{
        ssize_t res;
        char *out;

        out = calloc(size + 1, sizeof(char));
        assert(out != NULL);

        res = read(fd, out, size);
        assert_msg(res != -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error ocurred: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }

        out[size] = '\0';
        fprintf(stdout, "Inside function: %s\n", out);

        fprintf(stdout, "res: %d, size: %d, errno: (%d: %s)\n", res, size,
            errno, strerror(errno));

        *buf = out;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int fd;
        char *buf;

        buf = NULL;
        assert(argc == 2);

        errno = 0;
        fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        assert_msg(fd != -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error ocurred: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }

        wrapper(fd, &buf, AMOUNT);
        fprintf(stdout, "Outside function: %s\n", buf);

        free(buf);

        return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

1. I pass a filename as an input argument. It was a bit easier for me instead of hardcoding the name.
2. As you can see, inside my `wrapper()` implementation I allocate memory for an `out` buffer which size I am passing by a value of `size` variable. I know that the same value as `AMOUNT` value defined as macro but it would be easy to change in any other solution.
3. Then, I read given amount of characters using `read(2)` syscall, from a file descriptor returned by `open(2)` syscall in `main()` function which I pass to `wrapper()`.
4. At the end of that function I tell that I would like to save an address to the beginning of allocated `out` buffer and I would like that `*buf` indicates on that address. It is a buffer of `size + 1` `char` elements, allocated on heap, not on a local stack. Therefore program cannot "reuse" that addresses during his execution. Every address for variables declared like `int a;`,  `struct type name;` or `char tab[10];` are "freed" automatically after the end of function and you do not have an access to it. To be clear, you may have an access (e.g. print data from address saved to indicator) but you cannot be sure that you would not lose the data being saved there. Space allocated manually still exist on a heap until calling `free(3)` function.

So if we would do something like:

```
void
wrapper(int fd, char **buf, const size_t size)
{
        ssize_t res;
        char out[size];

        (...)

        *buf = out;
}
```

you may lost your data being saved on a local stack during continuing program execution.

Additionally, in my solution I also defined my own macro `assert_msg(x)` which is able to run `assert(3)` function and shows a text message with error. But it is only a feature but thanks to that we are able to see string corresponding to an `errno` number.

Of course, my program need better handling errors but it had to present the idea only.

Furthermore, you should also specify file permissions during using `open(2)` syscall as a third argument. It looks similar to the second argument because it is a bitwise 'or' separated list of values. Example flags: `S_IRUSR`, `S_IRGRP`, `S_IWOTH` etc.
In that argument, you can also just write proper value describing permissions, for example `0755`.